# Showing private videos of youtube in php

Tags: php

I am trying to show my private videos which i uploaded in youtube in my php project.Followings is my php code,

```
<?php
//Get videos from channel by YouTube Data API
$API_key    = 'YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY';
$channelID  = 'YOUR_YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID';
$maxResults = 10;

$videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Videos from YouTube Channel </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container{padding: 15px;}
    .youtube-video h2{font-size: 16px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach($videoList->items as $item){
        //Embed video
        if(isset($item->id->videoId)){
            echo '<div id="'. $item->id->videoId .'" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 youtube-video">
                    <iframe width="280" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <h2>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h2>
                </div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But am getting following error,

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UC40vLh6NqMw_F-QINO-keJg&maxResults=10&key=AIzaSyDLrY): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\channels\index.php on line 9

Notice: Trying to get property 'items' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\channels\index.php on line 31
```

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\channels\index.php on line 31

Can you please help me to solve it

Comment: If you replace your API_Key in `$API_key  = 'YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY';` you might also want to do so in your "_Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com..._" - everyone can read it. Delete the question and start again. And maybe change that APIkey on YT if possible

Comment: I have added orginal api key on that, but while posting question i cant post my orginal ids

Answer (score 0):

There is likely nothing wrong with your code.

You have simply **exceeded the usage limits of that account with that api key**